# Definition of Lie derivative by Hitchlin

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-derivative

I am following Hitchlin notes on differentiable manifolds:

> Now suppose $Y$ is a vector field, considered as a map $Y : M → TM$.
>   With a diffeomorphism $F : M → M$, its derivative $DF_x : T_x →
>  T_{F(x)}$ gives $DF_x(Y_x) ∈ T_{F(x)}$
>
> This defines a new vector field $\tilde{Y}$ by $$Y_{F(x)} =
>  DF_x(\tilde{Y}_x) \ \ \ \ \qquad (6) $$ Thus for a function f,
>   $$(\tilde{Y})(f ◦ F) = (Y f) ◦ F \qquad \quad (7)$$ Now if $F = ϕ_t$
>   for a one-parameter group (**add:** corresponding to a vector field
>   X), we have $\tilde{Y}_t$ and we can differentiate to get $$Y˙ =
>  \frac{∂} {∂t}\tilde{Y}_t \left. \right|_{t=0}$$ From (7) this gives
>   $Y˙f + Y(Xf) = XY f$ so that $Y˙ = XY − Y X$ is the natural derivative
>   defined above.

I don't understand the last sentence: how the equation 7 gives us this relation? If I use the flow, I have
$$XYf = \frac{∂} {∂t} (Y(f) \circ \phi_t) \left. \right|_{t=0}$$
But I don't see how it is linked to the sum in the last sentence. Can someone helps me understand this?

Comment: Hint: differentiate $(7)$ with respect to $t$ and evaluate at $t=0$

Comment: Ok so the last step I am stuck with is to show $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \tilde{Y}_t (f \circ \phi_t) \left. \right|_{t=0} = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \tilde{Y}_t(f) \left. \right|_{t=0} + Y(\frac{\partial}{\partial t} (f \circ \phi_t) \left. \right|_{t=0})$. I understand why it is true, but I can't prove it :S

Comment: I think it is Hitchin and not Hitchlin

Answer (score 2):

Use the flow, I think you should have 
 $$
 \frac{∂} {∂t}\tilde{Y}_t \left. \right|_{t=0} (f) = \lim_{t\to0} \frac{Y(f\circ \phi_{-t}) \circ \phi_{t} - Y(f)}{t}.
$$